# Changing the endianess of a PEM-encoded private/public key pair for the purpose of CryptoAPI-compatible signatures in libcrypto

Tags: endianness, cryptoapi, libcrypto

I am writing a program which is able to sign and verify signatures originally made for CryptoAPI(The old Windows crypto library). The goal is to be able to sign/verify from linux.

However, i seem to be hitting a wall due to CryptoAPI and libcrypto having different endianess.

I have alread tried to reverse the order of the signature to be verified(entire 128 byte RSA-encrypted chunk with padding and all). This does not seem to be enough, and i am struggling to find a proper straight forward recipe to do this easily.

I found from another stackoverflow post that you need to reverse the endianess of the actual key. Therefore, i am wondering if there is any easy way of doing this, where i preferably don't have to mess around with the data myself.

I will stick to verification, as i assume the same workflow can be applied to a private key PEM. The situation is like this:

I have the public key as PEM, converted using the command

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform MS\ PUBLICKEYBLOB -in pkey_mspublic.bin -outform PEM -out pubkey.pem
```

The following is how i load the PEM into libcrypto, and verify the signature:

```
BIO* certBio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)pubkey, -1);

RSA* rsa = NULL;
rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(certBio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);

for (int i=0; i <signatureLength; i++)
{
   char tmp = expectedHashPtr[i];
   expectedHashPtr[i] = expectedHashPtr[signatureLength - 1 - i];
   expectedHashPtr[signatureLength - 1 - i] = tmp;
}

EVP_PKEY* pubKey  = EVP_PKEY_new();
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pubKey, rsa);
std::cout << "pubkey size: " << EVP_PKEY_size(pubKey) << std::endl;
EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

if(!(mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create())) std::cout << "ctx create fail" << std::endl;

if(1 != EVP_VerifyInit(mdctx, EVP_md5())) std::cout << "digest init fail" << std::endl;

if(1 != EVP_VerifyUpdate(mdctx, data, 512)) std::cout << "digest fail" << std::endl;

std::cout << "finishing verify" << std::endl;
if(1 == EVP_VerifyFinal(mdctx, (unsigned char*)expectedHashPtr, signatureLength, pubKey))
{
    /* Success */
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
else
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

When i run the above code, i get padding errors, which i think is happening because my key is wrong endianess, and therefore wrong:

```
140278264301376:error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding:crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:67:
140278264301376:error:04067072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:padding check failed:crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:582:
```

So, my question is, is there a quick and easy way of handling endianess conversion of public and private key in PEM format? I do not want to do this by hand, as it has to scale.

Comment: you can just export key in PEM format from CryptoAPI without the need to change it byte order, see CryptExportObject with PKCS7_ASN_ENCODING